axios not working while running app from localhost:3000 on a macbook
I am trying to test some unobtrusive javascript code that needs to make an axios.get call to pre-populate a express handlebars form.  The javascript code is running and I am able to make it to the axios.get line, but once it executes it falls right to the catch and I get a generic "Network Error".  If I change the url in the get to "http://www.google.com" it works.  If I try to call the endpoint directly from the browser it hit the endpoint.  I am on a new macbook pro that I just purchased, not sure if that makes a difference.  What do I need to change for this to work?
apiLibrary.js:
const retrieveInfo = async (data)  => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/car/location/${data.id}`);
        debugger;
        return {
            data: res.data
        };
    } catch (err) {
        debugger;
        if (err.response) {
            // There is an error response from the server
            // You can anticipate error.response.data here
            if (err.response.data && err.response.data.errors[0]) {
                return {
                    errorMessage: err.response.data.errors[0]
                };
            }
        } else if (err.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received
            // Error details are stored in error.reqeust
            return {
                errorMessage: err.request
            };
        } else {
            return {
                errorMessage: "Something went wrong."
            }
        }
    }
}

excerpt from carLocation.js (unobtrusive javascript file)
retrieveInfo({id: carLocationId}).then((data) => {
    address.value = data.address;
    city.value = data.city;
    state.value = data.state;
    zipCode.value = data.zipCode;
}).catch(({errorMessage}) => {
    carLocationServerErrorMessage.innerText = errorMessage;
})

bottom of handlebars layout file:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/apis.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/carLocation.js"></script>


Could you try to accessing the error code and check which http error code it is thrown?
